# Create a Grid in Polygon and fill it using geom_tile

Tags: r, maps, polygon

I would like to ask how to create a grid within a polygon and then fill the grid with colors datased on the grids coordinances.

For example fill each grid polygon with random color from 5 colors or something like that.

example data:

```
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(spdep)

URL <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_CZE_0_sp.rds"
data <- readRDS(url(URL))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = data, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), color = "black", fill = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a siimple example using `st_make_grid()` to create a grid within your polygon, and `brewer.pal()` to create a color palette to fill them with.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.2, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

p1 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0),c(1,0),c(1,1),c(0,1), c(0,0))))
grid <- st_make_grid(p1, n = 2)

number_of_cells <- length(grid)
colors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(number_of_cells, name = 'PuBuGn')

ggplot(grid) +
  geom_sf(fill = colors)
```

[image]

```r
#Example using multipolygon shapefile
nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#st_combine is used to make a single polygon since nc is a multipolygon shapefile
nc_grid <- st_make_grid(st_combine(nc), n = 20)

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = st_union(nc)) + geom_sf(data =nc_grid, fill = NA)
```

[image]

```r
nc_grid_sf <- as_Spatial(nc_grid) %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_transform(st_crs(nc))

# Keep grid only within polygon
st_intersection(nc_grid, st_union(nc)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi thank for good solution, however let say we have a polygon of big country like in the example and we want the grid to be 400 rows and columns - si there a way how to have numbers of rows and columns as a parametr so it does not have to be done manually “by hand”?

Comment: For Example using your example on the country polygon is not working for me:

`grid <- st_make_grid(data, n = 5)

number_of_cells <- length(grid)
colors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(number_of_cells, name = 'PuBuGn')

ggplot(grid) +
  geom_sf(fill = colors)`

Comment: Hi thank you very much just last 2 questions, is it possible to have grid ONLY inside the country polygon so it would copy shape of country and also fill the colours?

Comment: Thank you very much- helped me a lot

Comment: what if i want equal area grids? hoiw can I create those?